# Masonry seems to override bootstrap default responsive column width

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jquery-masonry

The following is a basic Masonry example:
https://jsfiddle.net/Smartix/n5ks39LL/

As you can see, I have a '.masonry-wrapper' row that contains 4 '.col-sm-6' divs.
So (as per standard bootstrap behaviour) at xs screen size, the 4 divs should expand to 100% width and stack one under the other. Basically they should behave like 4 col-xs-12 divs!!
BUT, because the columns have little content, Masonry decides on its own that they should have a width equal to their content!!

If you look at the fiddle, you will see that only div 4 behaves like a true col-xs-12 (because it has a line of text long enough)

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row masonry-wrapper">
    <div class="col-sm-6 item bc1">
        <p>Div 1</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 item bc2">
        <p>Div 2</p>
        <p>Div 2</p>
        <p>Div 2</p>
        <p>Div 2</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 item bc3">
        <p>Div 3</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 item bc4">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus sed hendrerit nisi. Donec vehicula magna eu tellus bibendum vehicula. Fusce tempus tellus purus, sed porta.
        </p>
    </div>

</div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var $container = $('.masonry-wrapper');
$container.masonry({itemSelector: '.item'});
```

CSS:

```
.bc1 {background-color: #00bfb2;}
.bc2 {background-color: #de9800;}
.bc3 {background-color: #ff69da;}
.bc4 {background-color: #38ff59;}
```

Is this a bug or a misconfiguration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare your .item style.

for example:

```
.item { width: 50%; } // 50% is equal to col-sm-6
```

To work for both device sizes add `mobile first` behaviour with media queries.
https://jsfiddle.net/nx6mjkqr/

**OLD**

Alternatively you can change your js code to:

```
$container.masonry({itemSelector: '.col-sm-6'});
```

But this only works if window size is `sm`.

Comment: This may be a step in the right direction, but (as explained in the question) I would like for the divs to behave exactly like in my fiddle (for screen sizes > = sm) and then have 100% width for screen sizes = xs

Comment: Basically, I want Masonry to respect Bootstrap col sizes. Can you please update your fiddle?

Comment: i added a new fiddle to fit your needs.

Comment: Yes, as soon as I wrote that comment I had the same idea... media queries. Please update the first part of your answer (so that the right solution is clear) and I will mark your post as the right one

Comment: Very good!! I think this question will be a great help for many other users!! Thank you very much